# Does Java with Oracle databases support parameterized prepared statements for safely executing a TRUNCATE TABLE statement?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I'm attempting to truncate a table using Java with an Oracle database. My goal is to achieve this while avoiding SQL injection vulnerabilities. Here's the code I've tried:

```
String tableName = "employee";
String truncateQuery = "TRUNCATE TABLE ?";
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(truncateQuery)) {
    statement.setString(1, tableName);
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

However, when I execute this code, I encounter an "invalid table name" error. I'm aware that concatenating the table name directly into the query string ("TRUNCATE TABLE" + tableName) could lead to command injection vulnerabilities.

I've also confirmed that the table name is valid, as executing "TRUNCATE TABLE employee" directly in the database works fine.

My question is: Is there a way to use query parameters effectively in this scenario to avoid SQL injection while truncating a table using prepared statements in Java with an Oracle database?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this securely.

Comment: No. You can't use bind variables on table names

Comment: I wonder why you are using user input to truncate a table. That seems like a terrible idea. What if the enter `users`?

Comment: Thanks , but how to avoid sql injection and truncate table ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am working on a workflow and the table name will be decided at run time dynamically

Comment: here I just added as an example table name =employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use query parameters effectively in this scenario to avoid SQL injection while truncating a table using prepared statements in Java with an Oracle database?

No you can't do that.  As commenters have stated, an SQL table name (or a column name, an expression and so on) cannot be parameterized a `PreparedStatment`.  Only values can be parameterized.

AFAIK, the same thing is true for JDBC drivers for all other database products.

> How to avoid SQL injection and truncate table?

You can avoid generating the SQL strings at all, and prepopulate (say) a `Map` to translate user supplied table names to `TRUNCATE` statements for each (known) table which is safe for users to truncate.

Alternatively you can create a list of "safe to truncate" tables and validate the user-supplied table name against that ... and then generate the SQL for the `TRUNCATE`.

Alternatively you can ensure that users cannot supply the table name.

---

The bottom line is that parameterizing an SQL table name in a `PreparedStatement` would only give you a false sense of security.  The bad guys could still cause mayhem by passing in a table name that *shouldn't* be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java. However, as Oracle database is involved and if you can use a stored procedure, you could pass table name to it and let the procedure truncate table passed as a parameter.

Something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_trunc (par_table_name in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'truncate table ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name (par_table_name);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3

SQL> exec p_trunc('test');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

[dbms_assert](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65377).sql_object_name

> verifies that the input parameter string is a qualified SQL identifier of an existing SQL object

which means that it'll prevent SQL injection you're worried about.

---

What's left for you - if you accept this suggestion - is to find out how to call a stored procedure from your Java program; a can't assist with that.

Comment: You would use a [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). Something like `CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call p_trunc(?)}"); cs.setString(1, "test"); if (!cs.execute()) { System.err.println("Could not truncate test."); }`